# How do I upgrade this embedded tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, embed, upgrade

I want to basically upgrade my tomcat version(on RHEL).

Always worked in an environment where my `war` file would be dumped into */webapps, on restart of tomcat, the `war` file would expand and the rest is history.

Now, the system I'm working on, has completely different folder structure.

Something like this:

```
[root@bliss ~]# ls /usr/local/blah/blu-app/WEB-INF/
accounts      faces-reports.xml  logging.properties             web-app_2_3.dtd
bin           faces-syscfg.xml   logging.properties-production  web-app_2_4.xsd
buildnum.txt  framework2007      perl                           web.xml
classes       host.xsd           settings                       work
deploy-root   java.policy        tags
events.xsd    lib                tld
[root@bliss ~]#
```

I can see some tomcat related jars here:

```
/usr/local/blah/blu-app/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-http.jar
/usr/local/blah/blu-app/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-util.jar
/usr/local/blah/blu-app/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar
```

**UPDATE**

So I did find out that the tomcat is embedded 'cuz I found the following code starting it:

```
tomcat = new Embedded();
tomcat.setCatalinaHome(targetPath);

Host host = tomcat.createHost("localhost", targetPath);
Context rootCtx = tomcat.createContext("", targetPath);
((StandardContext)rootCtx).setWorkDir("WEB-INF/work"); 
ServletContext servletContext = rootCtx.getServletContext();
servletContext.setAttribute("version", version);
ApplRealm realm = new ApplRealm(servletContext);
tomcat.setRealm(realm);

rootCtx.setPrivileged(true);

Engine engine = tomcat.createEngine();
engine.setName("tomcat");
engine.setDefaultHost("localhost");
host.addChild(rootCtx);
engine.addChild(host);
tomcat.addEngine(engine);

LOG.debug("starting tomcat");
tomcat.start();
LOG.debug("tomcat started");
// clear out any old sessions: see bug 17882
Session[] sessions = rootCtx.getManager().findSessions();
for (int i = 0; i < sessions.length; i++)
{
    sessions[i].expire();
}

ServerSocket socket = null;
socket = new ServerSocket(CmcUtils.getControlPort(), 2, InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"));
socket.accept();

LOG.info("Received shutdown command. Exiting !");

tomcat.stop();
```

The question then is, how do I upgrade this tomcat to say Tomcat6?

Replace with the latest jars in WEB-INF/lib? Which all jars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. It could be an embedded tomcat but it could also be a heavily customised tomcat configuration.

Check the startup script to determine which class is being invoked. If its the usual catalina its not embedded its just that they changed the config to point to another folder instead of webapps.

If it is indeed embedded then to upgrade u would need to replace the tomcat jars with new ones.

Comment: Thanks jbx, it was indeed embedded. Updated the question. Could you please take a look?

Comment: So, you would need to replace all the related Jars. Have a look at this link here. It is for Tomcat 7.0, but gives you a good idea.

http://nileshk.com/2010/08/25/emdedding-apache-tomcat-7-0.html

Comment: I would be very careful when attempting this. You have no guarantee that the Tomcat guys wouldn't have refactored the classes and changed class names, package names or method names, which could break the application's code. Do you have a specific reason why you need to upgrade?

Comment: Primarily cuz' client asked us to ;). But seriously for all the security fixes that comes with higher version.

Comment: Ok so try to replace jars and pray nothing breaks.  The Servlet spec does not  define embedded servlet engines so if any class/package/method the application is using from the tomcat jars was changed in the latest version, the application code will need to change too. Hopefully nothing changed but test thoroughly and watch out for those obscure exceptions when the engine starts.

Answer (score 0):

In tomcat we can create virtual hosts,i.e, making tomcat recognize application's which are deployed in external folders.

A lot more information can be found here.
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/host.html

In your given scenario, try to lookup in server.xml, which is usually found in conf folder of tomcat home.

Comment: I could not find server.xml! So there is no tomcat home and so this is emedded?

Comment: Did you do system wide search ?

Comment: You are going the long way this way. Start from the things u know. Check the script you use to start the application. If it looks like a normal tomcat startup.sh or catalina.sh it is not embedded. Embedded means your application starts tomcat programmatically.

Comment: Yes I did system wide search, updated the question. Thanks for your interest Ratna.